# Queue of SQLite accesses for multiple threads (for write and read commands)

Tags: java

How can I create a RingBuffer for sqlite queries.
So that when two threads access a sqlite-db at the same time no error occurs.

Since I have several different accesses I would outsource each access to its own function.

So I am looking for a way to create a queue of functions.

I would also like to mention that I need to use a SQLite DB.

I've been trying to solve this problem all day but I can't find a way.

Thank you very much.

Comment: While you might find a way to do this with SQLite, it isn't intended for such complex tasks. I suggest that you move to a full RDBMS like MySQL for parallel database tasks.

Comment: You can use tools like `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` to restrict access to resources.

Comment: Do you explicitely need to it to be a ring buffer? You could take a look at LinkedBlockingDeque  or ConcurrentLinkedDeque instead, already implemented and thread safe (the first one being more restrictive). That would simplify your logic to just add and get methods